# C# overloading ambiguity

Tags: c#, overloading, ambiguous-call

```
class Program
{
    public void x(int a, float b , float c) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method 1 ");
    }
    public void x(float a, int b,int c) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method 2 ");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program ob = new Program();
        ob.x(1, 2, 3);
    }
}
```

`ob.x(1,2,3)` is showing

> Error 1   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties: '`OverloadDemo.Program.x(int, float, float)`' and
>   '`OverloadDemo.Program.x(float, int,
>   int)`'
>
> C:\Users\Public\Videos\SampleVideos\Projectss\OverloadDemo\OverloadDemo\Program.cs    25  13  OverloadDemo

Method 2`has two arguments of`int`type and`Method 1`has two argumets of`int` type.
So Method 1 should be favoured.

Why is there an error ?

Comment: I couldn't find anything in C# spec that would say, that number of implicit conversions necessary to satisfy method parameters matters.

Comment: Then for what reason is the method 1 not favored ?

Comment: Because C# spec doesn't say it should?

Answer (score 2):

Due to the implicit conversion of `int` to `float`, the compiler cannot discern which method you intended to call. You'd have to be more intentional with the types:

```
ob.x(1f, 2, 3);
```

vs

```
ob.x(1, 2f, 3f);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this, would be while you're going to consume the method with this signature `public void x(int a, float b , float c)`, call it like this,

```
ob.x(1, 2.0f, 3.0f); // convert them to float
```

This would make sure that these are sent as float and the first param is sent as a integer. A sample to test this, is here, do test it out. https://dotnetfiddle.net/9yaKJa